# Injecting mockito-mocked beans into Spring Boot bean for testing still load dependencies

Tags: spring, unit-testing, spring-boot, mockito

Here is my test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes={AseCalculatorApplicationImplTestConfig.class})
public class AseCalculatorApplicationImplTest {

    @Autowired
    AseCalculatorApplicationImpl aseCalculatorApplicationImpl;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        Assert.assertNotNull(aseCalculatorApplicationImpl);
    }
}

@Configuration
class AseCalculatorApplicationImplTestConfig {

    @Bean
    public StaticBean staticBean() {
        return Mockito.mock(StaticBean.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public JmsTemplate jmsTopicTemplate() {
        return Mockito.mock(JmsTemplate.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public AseCalculatorApplicationImpl aseCalculatorApplicationImpl() {
        return new AseCalculatorApplicationImpl();
    }
}
```

My AseCalculatorApplicationImpl class has the autowired beans (no constructor or setters, autowired by refelection):

```
@Component
public class AseCalculatorApplicationImpl {

    @Autowired
    StaticBean staticBean;

    @Autowired
    JmsTemplate jmsTopicTemplate;

    [ ... omitted for brevity]
```

In My Static Bean it autowires a Hibernate Session Factory:

```
@Component
public class StaticBean {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory hibernateSessionFactory;

    [ ... omitted for brevity]
```

Now my understanding is that my AseCalculatorApplicationImplTestConfig will create a mock StaticBean, which is basically a Mockito empty shell, and not use any of the code / dependencies / beans from the class itself. And yet, I feel like I've tried every variation of creating my test beans, annotating them as @MockBean, annotating my Impl with @InjectMocks, and yet every time it fails with:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 
  No qualifying bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency [org.hibernate.SessionFactory]
```

I know I could change my Impl class and have a constructor marked as @Autowired that then sets my staticBean, but I like how clean it is not to have to do that. But I can't figure out what I've done wrong with my Test Config creating my mock Beans - why is it trying to inject the hibernateSessionFactory when the bean is mocked??

Comment: Your understanding is wrong. Yes it is an empty shell from a functional point of view. It still uses the same class definition (mockito simply extends your own class with a dynamic one!) and as such all annotations and fields are still there. As it is a spirng managed bean those still will be processed.

Comment: Ah I thought that Spring was the one that managed the annotiations, and by returning a Mockito mock class as a Bean that Spring would never look inside the class itself (ie at the annotations). So what is the solution? Create a mock bean for every autowired field in any mock bean (recursively)? I'm assuming the clever people that do Spring have solved for this? Or is my application badly designed and that's why I'm having this problem?

Comment: Create an Interface for bean and create a Mock on Interface either than class